# change google maps custom image marker depending on zoom level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using mosne map (www.mosne.it/playground/mosne_map)

What I'm trying to do is, whenever user change zoom level < 10 the image will be changed. Here's what I got now:
currently the marker doesn't change whenever user changes zoom level

```
$.fn.mosne_map = function (options) {

    var baseconf = {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var s_infobox = {
        content: "",
        disableAutoPan: false,
        maxWidth: 0,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-110, 5),
        zIndex: null,
        boxStyle: {
            background: "url('images/infobox_top.png') top center no-repeat",
            opacity: 1,
            color: '#fff',
            padding: '0',
            width: "300px"
        },
        closeBoxMargin: "16px 4px",
        closeBoxURL: "images/infobox_close_hd2.png",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        isHidden: false,
        pane: "floatPane",
        enableEventPropagation: false
    };

    defaults = {

        elements: '#list .maplocation', //links selector
        map_opt: baseconf, // custom map options object
        clat: -9.460181,  // set the lat default map center
        clng: 100.988281, // set the lng default map center
        mapstyle_name: '', // custom map style label and id
        mapstyle: '', // mapstyle object
        cluster_styles: {}, // custom cluster icons object
        marker_icon: {}, // custom marker icon url,width,height
        infowindows: true, // shows infoWindows grabing html from the .infobox element
        infobox: false, // enable custom infoWindows using infobox class
        infobox_s: s_infobox, // default color scheme for custom infobox container
        trigger: 'map_open', // you can set a event trigger for each link/marker
        clickedzoom: 15, // set the zoom level when you click the single marker
        timeout: 100, // delay between click and zoom on the single marker
        mode: 'latlng', // switch mode
        wait: 500, // timeout between geocode requests
        maxtry: 10, // limit of time to bypass query overlimit
        cat_style: {}, // costum icons and click zoom level
        fitbounds: false, // on|off fit bounds
        defzoom: 3, // default zoom level if fitbounds is off
        showzoom: false, // bind current map zoom level event
        before: function () {}, // before create map callback
        after: function () {}, // after create map callback 
        afterUpdate: function () {} // after update map callback
    };

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this.each(function () {

        var map_el = $(this);
        var the_map_el = $(this).get(0);

        //on before
        settings.before.apply(map_el);





        //init map
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(settings.clat, settings.clng);





        var map = new google.maps.Map(the_map_el, settings.map_opt);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, null, settings.cluster_styles);

        map.setCenter(center);


        bounds.extend(center);


        map.setZoom(settings.defzoom);
        map.setCenter(center);

        //apply map style
        if (settings.mapstyle_name != '') {
            var styledMapOptions = {
                name: settings.mapstyle_name
            };
            var m_MapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(settings.mapstyle, styledMapOptions);
            map.mapTypes.set(settings.mapstyle_name, m_MapType);
            map.setMapTypeId(settings.mapstyle_name);
        }

        // set markers icons     
            var markerIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/img/google-marker-big.png");



        // init infowindow 
        if (settings.infowindows) {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                maxWidth: 200
            });
        }

        // init infobox
        if (settings.infobox) {
            var boxText = document.createElement("div");
            boxText.style.cssText = settings.infobox_s_txt
            boxText.innerHTML = "hello world";
            var m_box = new InfoBox(settings.infobox_s);
        }

        // function create marker

        var _createMarker = function (el, latLng, markerIcon, m_name, cat) {

            if (cat) {
                var c_icon = settings.cat_style[cat]['icon'];
                var c_icon_w = settings.cat_style[cat]['width'];
                var c_icon_h = settings.cat_style[cat]['height'];

                if (c_icon) { //var markerIcon =  c_icon;
                    var markerIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(c_icon, null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(c_icon_w, c_icon_h));
                }

            }

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                icon: markerIcon,
                flat: true,
                title: m_name
            });

            //extend bounds
            bounds.extend(latLng);

            // bind click on map trigger event fill infowindow / infobox content on demand 
            if (settings.infowindows || settings.infobox) {
                var content = el.find('.infobox').html();
            }

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                if (settings.infowindows) {
                    infowindow.close();
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    map.setCentexxxr(marker.getPosition());
                }
                if (settings.infobox) {
                    m_box.close();
                    $(boxText).hide();
                    m_box.setContent(content);
                    m_box.open(map, marker);
                    $(boxText).show("slow");
                    map.setCentesr(marker.getPosition());
                }

                el.trigger(settings.trigger);

                $(el).parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
                $(el).addClass('active');


                setTimeout(function () {
                    map.setZoom(settings.clickedzoom);
                    map.panTo(latLng);
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
                }, settings.timeout);

            });

            // trigger click on list 
            $(el).find('.maplink').unbind("click").bind("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
                return false;
            });

            markerCluster.addMarker(marker);

        };

        var _m_geocode = function (el, geocoder, address, name, cat, j) {

            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latLng = results[0].geometry.location;

                    _createMarker(el, latLng, markerIcon, name, cat);
                    if (settings.fitbounds === true) {
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);

                    }
                } else {

                    if (status === "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            //console.log("trying again "+g_address);
                            j++;
                            if (j <= settings.maxtry) {
                                _m_geocode(el, geocoder, address, name, cat, j);
                            } else {
                                $(el).css({
                                    opacity: .35
                                });
                            }
                        }, settings.wait);

                    } else if (status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                        $(el).css({
                            opacity: .35
                        });
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        //

        $(map_el).bind('update', function () {

            //reset cluster and bounds
            markerCluster.clearMarkers();
            bounds = null;
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            // markers loop     
            var markers = [];
            var w_delay = 0;

            if (settings.mode === 'address') {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            }


            var totel = $(settings.elements).length;


            $(settings.elements).each(function (i) {

                // create marker
                var el = $(this);

                //mode geocoding
                if (settings.mode === 'address') {

                    var mkr = el.data();
                    var name = $(this).find(".name").text();
                    var address = $(this).find(".address").text();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        _m_geocode(el, geocoder, address, name, mkr.cat, 0);
                    }, settings.wait * i);

                } else {

                    // mode latlng
                    var mkr = el.data();
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mkr.lat, mkr.lng);
                    _createMarker(el, latLng, markerIcon, mkr.name, mkr.cat);

                }

                //end of the elements loop
            });

            if (settings.fitbounds === true) {

                // log(bounds);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                if (totel == 1) {
                    map.setZoom(settings.clickedzoom);
                }
                if (totel == 0) {
                    map.setZoom(settings.defzoom);
                    map.setCenter(center);
                }
                // map.setCenter(center);
            } else {
                //map.setZoom(settings.defzoom);
                //map.setCenter(center);
            };


            //callbak afterUpdate 
            settings.afterUpdate.apply(map_el);

        }).trigger('update');

        $(map_el).bind('bounds', function () {
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });

        // nice zoom status 
        if (settings.showzoom) {

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                $(map_el).trigger("showzoom", [map.getZoom()]);
            });

        };




        //on after
        settings.after.apply(map_el);

        return true;

        //change markerIcon
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            var zoom = map.getZoom();

            if (zoom <= 10) {
                var markerIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Vg5.png");
            }
            else {
                var markerIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/img/google-marker-big.png")
            }
        });


    });




};
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the existing code?  Note that you actually need to call the [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) .setIcon method on an existing marker to change its icon.

Comment: @geocodezip, sorry, just edited the question... the code doesn't work, the custome marker doesn't change when people change zoom level to >10.

Comment: How do you create your map? How do you create and add your markers to the map?

Comment: i've updated the full code. sorry, I'm a newbie in gmaps. been trying to solve this for days, but still no solution. thanks, @geocodezip

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the issue.  From what is posted I can't see how you add markers to the map.  For that matter, I can't see the markers. Perhaps a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) might let us see your code in action.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sp0m3yg6/) I'm trying to copy it on fiddle.  but I dont know why it doesn't work. Here's the direct link: [link](http://banyakdiskon.com/map/), any thanks @geocodezip

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for a single icon(not a single marker, this method will change the icon of all markers, but there is also an option to define category-markers)

This is the code that currently defines the default-icon:

```
// set markers icons     
   var markerIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/img/google-marker-big.png");
```

Replace it with this code:

```
// set markers icons     
  var markerIcon = new google.maps.MVCObject();


  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function(){
     markerIcon.set('icon',(this.getZoom()<10)
     ? 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png'//url  for zoom<10
     : 'http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/img/google-marker-big.png'//url  for zoom>=10
     );
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(map,'zoom_changed',{});
```

The url of `markerIcon` now will be updated when the zoom changes

To apply the changes to the markers replace this code:

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            icon: markerIcon,
            flat: true,
            title: m_name
        });
```

with.....

```
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                icon: markerIcon.icon,
                flat: true,
                title: m_name
            });
            marker.bindTo('icon',markerIcon,'icon') ;
```